# How to maintain element within a loop running async code. Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, state, fetch-api

I am looping through some elements on a page and then fetching some data with a `GET` request using the `fetch api`

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[data-custom-price='true']")).forEach(function (ele, idx) {
    let params = {};
    params.dataType = "text";
    params.headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' };

    fetch("/subscriptions/getfees?product=" + ele.dataset.item, params).then(function (response) {
        resp = response;
        return response.text();
    }).then(function (result) { 
        ele.innerHTML = result;
    });
}
```

This works absolutely fine.

BUT.. for brevity and various other reasons, I have built a sort of lightened jQuery type library of my own to commonise a bunch of stuff within my code and have this:

```
t$.get = function (url, params) {       
    // A bunch of checks and defaults on params...     
    fetch(url, params).then(function (response) { 
        return response.text();
    }).then(function (result) {
        params.success(result);
    });
}
```

I run the above loop like this:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[data-custom-price='true']")).forEach(function (ele, idx) {
    // We are now looping through these elements and running the `GET` async call, updating the innerHTML of each element as the server returns the response from the URL.
    // There is no need to update these elements sequentially, the code should be entirely asyncronous.
    // The problem is that each instance of `t$.get` is not return to the unique `ele` that initiated it.
    // WHEREAS in the example above where I use `fetch` directly, it all works as per my expectation/requirements.
    t$.get(
       url, 
       {
           success: function (result){
               ele.innerHTML = result;
           }
       }
    )
 }
```

If I loop like this the element state is not being maintained. It will only update the last element in the loop, not each one as it loops.

How do I maintain this element with this asynchronous code when passing it off to a separate function?

Comment: What is `paras.success`?

Comment: So where do you update the element and reference it?

Comment: ok, I will update the question.

Comment: Question updated with params.success function and the updating of the element

Comment: You still seem to have errors in your code, e.g. `paras.url` instead of simply `url`, `response fetch(...)` which seems like invalid syntax. You also didn't share e.g. how `url` is composed. Note that you don't await your promises/async function calls.

Comment: Sorry, there are typos everywhere. This is obviously all part of a much bigger section of code. I will update the typos. The problem is in my (lack of) understanding of promises in the async calls. I want each call to run asynchronously, there is no need to wait for one before running another, but I am losing the `element` in the loop so that only the last element is updated, rather than each as and when the response is received from the URL.